# Dividing a Pizza with N Lines

Tags: divisibility

How many regions can we divide a pizza with n lines?

I can not find a formula.

Lines   Pieces
0       1
1       2
2       4

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000124

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the *Lazy Caterer's Sequence* as given in: https://oeis.org/A000124

The formula is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1$, where $n$ starts from $0$.

A simple proof can be found here in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence

Answer (score 1):

Lazy caterer's sequence formula:

$p=\frac{n^{2} + n + 2}{2}$

Comment: It would be nice if you could present at least a sketch of how this formula is deduced.